# How to resize a div with screen size change?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a responsive layout which includes `main content` and `sidebar`. 
Sidebar should be in the right side of the main content, and once screen size changes till 600px, it goes to the bottom of `main content`. 
The problem is that when `screen width > 600px`, `sidebar div` doesn't resize/reduce and doesn't adjust/fit with the browser. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Can't figure out how to make it resizable.
Here is the code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

.sidebar-section {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.sidebar button {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #ccc;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.articleSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.articleSection img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  @supports (display: grid) {
    .site {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(6, minmax(auto, 10em)) 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: minmax(1em, auto) 1fr auto minmax(1em, auto);
      gap: 20px;
    }
    .content {
      grid-column: 2/7;
    }
    .sidebar {
      grid-column: 7/8;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <section class="site">
      <main class="content">
        <section class="articleSection">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="prod" />
          <article>
            <p class="description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            </p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </main>
      <aside class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-section">
          <button>
              <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Write message
            </button>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.sidebar-section` had been given a fixed width of 300px. Therefore the sidebar will exceed the grid column assigned to it. Try removing it, which will result it being assign a value of `auto` by default and fits the column nicely.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

.sidebar-section {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* width: 300px; */
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.sidebar button {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #ccc;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.articleSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.articleSection img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  @supports (display: grid) {
    .site {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(6, minmax(auto, 10em)) 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: minmax(1em, auto) 1fr auto minmax(1em, auto);
      gap: 20px;
    }

    .content {
      grid-column: 2/7;
    }

    .sidebar {
      grid-column: 7/8;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section class="site">
        <main class="content">
          <section class="articleSection">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="prod" />
            <article>
              <p class="description">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              </p>
            </article>
          </section>
        </main>
        <aside class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar-section">
            <button>
              <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Write message
            </button>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```